# Body margin-top and header margin-top both margins from the top of the browser

Tags: html, css

Let's say body is set to margin-top:20px and then inside body there's header which is set also to margin-top:20px. So shouldn't technically header margin from the top of the body which is already 20px off from browser top? Because in my situation header margin-top doesn't work at all/or it also simply margins off of the browser top side.

It should be body 20px off and then header 20px off from body (so it should be technically header is off 40px from the top of the browser).

Comment: Its hard to say why something 'doesnt work at all' with out seeing any code.  Since you are formatting the header, could you just give your body a margin-top:40px; and give the header no margin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The margins of both elements are [collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). That's why you only see the margin from `body`.

If `body` must have a top margin, you can offset the `header` element by applying `padding-top: 20px` to `body` instead of `margin-top: 20px` to `header`.